# How to handle the Multiple datatype values entered in a textbox for searching purpose

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, textbox

Below is the Xaml code where we have one Combobox which contains the database column name (hardcoded). Next, there's a textbox which will take the value to be searched under that ComboBox Selected type value.
**Xaml Code**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Search By" Width="100"/>
                <ComboBox Name="CmbSearch" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ColNames}" SelectedValue="{Binding SearchBy}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Enter the Value" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox Name="T" Style="{StaticResource Txt}" Text="{Binding Searching,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
<DataGrid Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding customer}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
    Height="310" Width="310" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path='Id',UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path='Name',UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Path='Age',UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Path='Country',UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Path='Active',UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource convert}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete Record" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdDeleteUser, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Width="60" Margin="2"  Content="Delete" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private string _SearchBy;

        public string SearchBy  
        {
            get { return _SearchBy; }
            set { _SearchBy = value;
                
               OnPropertyChange("SearchBy"); 
                
                
            }
        }

        private string _Searching;

        public string Searching
        {
            get { return _Searching; }
            set
            {
                _Searching = value;
                OnPropertyChange("Searching");
                if (Searching != null)
                { 
                     collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<Object>(Search);
                    
                }


            }
        }
        private bool Search(Object obj)
        {
            
            Customer cus = (Customer)obj;
            if((SearchBy.Equals("ID")))
            {
                if (cus.Id.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(Searching)))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                
            }
            else if(SearchBy.Equals("Name")) 
            {
                if (cus.Name.Contains(Searching))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if(SearchBy.Equals("Age")) 
            {
                if (cus.Age.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(Searching)))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if(SearchBy.Equals("Country"))
            {
                if (cus.Country.Contains(Searching))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if(SearchBy.Equals("Active"))
            {

                if (cus.Active.Equals(Convert.ToBoolean(Searching)))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }                    
        }
```

The Search for Name and country are working fine but Id, Age, and Active are having type issues. I also created an IValueconverter for Active(which is a Combobox). What should I do for the other type?

Comment: searchby is a string. You need to parse strings to give different types. Tryparse allows you to check if it converts.  eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `int.TryParse` method to try to parse the string value and then call `Equals`.

You should use the `switch` statement. Your `Search` method could then be implemented something like this:

```
private bool Search(Object obj)
{
    Customer cus = (Customer)obj;
    switch (_SearchBy)
    {
        case "ID":
            return int.TryParse(_Searching, out int id) && cus.Id.Equals(id);
        case "Name":
            return cus.Name.Contains(Searching);
        case "Age":
            return int.TryParse(_Searching, out int age) && cus.Age.Equals(age);
        case "Country":
            return cus.Country.Contains(Searching);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This helped me solve the ID and Age field issue. But I still can't figure out the solution for the ACTIVE field which is a Boolean type.